# How to host a static landpage and react on the same node server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

Currently, I have a static landing page hosted on firebase on the url "mycompany.com" (not the actual URL).
My node server (using express) runs on heroku and it contains my backend API and my react frontend (using react-router). In order to make everything run, I had to point this to a subdomain: app.mycompany.com

What I really wanted to do, was to have my landing page on "/" and have that to be the default redirect, all hosted in my node server (without having to have two servers and point to a subdomain).

I'm struggling to understand how could I set up this, or if have to change something to make this work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a static build of your react app you can serve this build folder along with your static landing page. You'll still have to specify the path where you want your app traffic to go:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const staticLandingPage = express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./path/to/landingpage"));
const reactApp = express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./path/to/reactBuild"));
app.use("/", staticLandingPage);
app.use("/app", reactApp);
```